# Mongodb query docs with not unique field for unique result

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Lets say that our model is like:

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
  doc: String
});
var Schema = mongoose.model('Collection', schema);
```

where doc is not unique, we can have many of same. Now I would like to query 10 latest docs with unique doc value.
In case latest 10 docs have same value, only one should be pulled and other 9 from next latest.
Ignoring the uniqueness of query field doc, we would have something like:

```
Schema.find({}).sort({'_id': -1}).limit(10).exec(function(err, docs) {
     // those docs here can have same value of doc field.
});
```

What I do now with javascript, which solve the case, but query is heavy:

```
var same = {};
for (var i = docs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(same[docs[i].doc]) docs.splice(i, 1);
    else same[docs[i].doc] = true;
}
docs = docs.slice(0, 9);
```

Comment: And what exactly defines "uniqueness" to you? Show some documents which you current return and what you would like to return. Determining "uniqueness" is not a global concept. It's only ever what "you" perceive as "unique". The `_id` itself is always "unique", but the rest of the document content is up to you. Please share.

Comment: Tried .distinct('_id') ?

Comment: Don't care what you tried. Just show what you have and what you want. `distinct()` works for "one field" of course, but we need to know what your "multiple unique fields" actually are.

Comment: checking distinct at the moment

Comment: distinct is not a solution, you can't .limit with ti